# Visual Studio 2019: Only TODO tokens appear in Task List

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019 with C#.

in my Task List I only see "TODO" tokens, but all my own tokens have disappeared from Task List (the Tokens still exist in the source code)
I don't know when or why this happened, I did nothing unusal, just several Updates of Visual Studio (and Windows 10)

I could not find any useful hints using Google so maybe somebody here does know how to rebuild\refresh the Task List?
And there must be a place where the Task List Information is stored (cache?) - maybe it would help to delete it..?

Comment: I did some tests... this problem appears after Visual Studio Updates.... so it seems that a VS update breaks the Task List

Comment: Check this for latest update on this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1041405/custom-task-list-tokens-no-longer-working-in-vs-20.html

Answer (score 2):

> how to rebuild\refresh the Task List

The token list can be found at Options → Environment → Task List.
If tokens aren't there, you probably lost them forever.

[image: Tokens]

Also, you can check Import and Export settings
[image]

If you'll open that file, you could find category named `TaskList` — that's where your tokens are stored. If the ones you find missing aren't there, then you completely lost your old tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that this is a bug in VS and will be fixed in a future release of VS (probably in version 16.7)